# select multiple columns from two different tables, merge and then insert into another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

```
T1    T2           T3    T4
ID    ID A B C     ID    
---   --------     ---   ---
1     3  u v w      3
2     4  x y z      4
```

First I have to select the items from B that have the IDs retrieved from C as so:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM T2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T3)

--will return u,v,w
              x,y,z
```

Now I want to retrieve the IDs in T1 and merge them with each row returned from the above query and insert them into T4:

```
   1   u v w
   1   x y z
   2   u v w
   2   x y z
```

Comment: How is T1 joined to T2 or T3?

Comment: T1 and T3 are temp tables. no relationship at all. however the values in t3 can be linked to rows in T2.

Comment: I want every combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option with CROSS JOIN

```
INSERT T4(ID, A, B, C)
SELECT t1.ID, o.A, o.B, o.C
FROM T1 t1 CROSS JOIN (
                       SELECT a,b,c 
                       FROM T2 t2 JOIN T3 t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID
                       ) o
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d627bc/1)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this can help:

```
INSERT INTO T4
SELECT ID, A, B, C 
FROM    (SELECT a,b,c FROM T2 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM T3)) tab1
        CROSS JOIN T1
```